# How to generate data structure from template?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have got data template:

```
templ: [
    lots: [
        lot: [
            name: none
            objs: [
                obj: [
                    code: none
                ]
            ]           
        ]
    ]
]
```

And tape of data like: `lot obj lot obj obj lot obj lot obj obj`.
The idea is next. I need to detenare result data structure by tape data.
`lot obj` - lot with one object
`lot obj obj` - lot with two objects

and so on. So from:
`lot obj`

The result should be same as original data:

```
lots: [
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]
        ]           
    ]
]
```

From:
`lot obj obj` it should be:

```
lots: [
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]           
        ]           
    ]
]
```

From:
`lot obj lot obj obj lot obj lot obj obj`

should be:

```
lots: [
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]           
        ]           
    ]
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]               
        ]           
    ]
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]           
        ]           
    ]       
    lot: [
        name: none
        objs: [
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]
            obj: [
                code: none
            ]               
        ]           
    ]
    
]
```

I am giving data structure in pseudo-code because I am not sure what proper data structure I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.split('lot')` and `list.count('obj')` to figure out the number of objects in every lot:

```py
txt = 'lot obj lot obj obj lot obj lot obj obj'

lot_counts = [lot.count('obj') for lot in txt.split('lot')[1:]]
# [1, 2, 1, 2]

lots = [{'name': None, 'objs': [{'code': None} for _ in range(lot_count)]} for lot_count in lot_counts]
# [{'name': None, 'objs': [{'code': None}]},
#  {'name': None, 'objs': [{'code': None}, {'code': None}]},
#  {'name': None, 'objs': [{'code': None}]},
#  {'name': None, 'objs': [{'code': None}, {'code': None}]}]
```

About your remark "I am giving data structure in pseudo-code because I am not sure what proper data structure I should use.":

I can't help you figure out what data structure to use, since your question gives no context what this is for.

Comment: I need to generate structure by names that I am getting from input as list of strings.

Comment: Can you give an example input? Also, what are these structures going to be used for once they're generated?